# Nested guards on Haskell

Tags: haskell

Haskell disallows the following style of nested guards although they look aesthetically natural and concise:

```
x | condition_1
    | condition_1_1
      | condition_1_1_1 = expression_1_1_1
      | ...
    | ...
  | ...
```

I got a few pointers e.g. [1](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2007-December/020019.html) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124558/is-it-possible-to-nest-guards-in-haskell), but still can't help ask:

Needn't we bother such negligible syntactical sugar?

Would the implementation introduce prohibitive incompatibility?

Do deep nested guards resonate too much with imperative programming to easily promote them?

Comment: I wanted this for forever. I was really disappointed to learn it wasn't possible.

Comment: Guards do not participate in layout, so your suggested syntax would be highly ambiguous.

Comment: What Reid Barton suggests is, I guess, the most likely reason why no one bothered yet. In general, I don't think concerns such as "resonate too much with imperative programming" hold much water -- after all, we have `if`, `case` and `do` already. On the other hand, I believe this sort of nesting remove most of the clarity adding by the guards syntax, so we might as well just use nested `if`.