# Check a list if sorted in ascending or descending or not sorted in haskell?

Tags: list, sorting, haskell

I am new in Haskell. I just studied Haskell for two weeks now. I don't really understand how the if else statement and the list comprehension for haskell works. So I wanted to make function that can figure out the sort type such as the list is sorted in ascending or descending or not sorted at all. I know how to check if the list is sorted ascending and descending but I don't know how to check if the list is not sorted at all.

```
data SortType = Ascending | Descending | NotSorted deriving (Show)

sorted :: (Ord a) => [a] -> TypeOfSort 
sorted [] = Ascending
sorted [x] = Ascending
sorted (x:y:xs) | x < y = sorted (y:xs) 
            | otherwise = Descending
sorted_  = Ascending
```

It would be a great help if someone could tell me how to do it. Thank you.
P/s: this is not a homework/work stuffs but rather something I want to learn.

Comment: Hint: there's a fourth possibility, which is that the list contains a single value repeated _n_ times. Such a list is not _not sorted_, but it's not exactly sorted ascending or descending either. Think about how your beliefs about a given list might change between these four possibilities as you examine it element by element.

Comment: `Ascending` and `Descending`, strictly speaking, really only apply to lists without duplicates. The more general terms `Nondecreasing` and `Nonincreasing` could describe lists that could have duplicate items, and both apply equally well to the degenerate case of a single repeated item.

Comment: and this is *not* list comprehension! this is ["guards"](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#.7C).

Comment: @chepner how do I check if the list have duplicate?

Comment: @WillNess I've tried that but it gave me "parse error in input '|' "

Comment: @JayRowen you have to follow a specific syntax. to see an example, go to https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html and search for "guard".

Comment: you can also [search for "haskell guard" on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=haskell+guard). examples of using `where` with them see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124558/is-it-possible-to-nest-guards-in-haskell). do note that "pattern guard" is another, different concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A problematic part of your function is the `| otherwise = Descending`. According to your function definition, if there are two consecutive examples in the list such that `x >= y`, then the function is *descending*. This is not `True`: a function is descending if for *all* two consecutive elements `x > y` (or `x >= y` if you do not require it to be *strictly* descending).

Furthermore an additional problem here is that a list with one element (or no elements) can be seen as both `Ascending` and `Descending`. So I think the first thing we have to do is define some semantics. We can decide to make the output a list of `TypeOfSort` items, or we can decide to extend the number of options of `TypeOfSort`.

In this answer I will pick the last option. We can extend `TypeOfSort` to:

```
data TypeOfSort = Ascending | Descending | Both | NotSorted
    deriving (Show)
```

Now we can work on the function itself. The base cases here are of course the empty list `[]` and the list with one element `[_]`:

```
sorted [] = Both
sorted [_] = Both
```

Now we need to define the inductive case. When is a list sorted ascendingly? If all elements are (strictly) larger than the previous element. Analogue a list is sorted descending if all elements are (strictly) smaller than the previous element. Let us for now assume *strictness*. It is easy to alter the function definition later.

So in case we have a list with two or more elements, a list is `Ascending` if the list that starts with the second element is `Ascending` or `Both`, and `x < y`, or in other words:

```
sorted (x:y:xs) | Both <- sort_yxs, x < y = Ascending
                | Ascending <- sort_yxs, x < y = Ascending
    where sort_yxs = sorted (y:xs)
```

The same holds for descending order: if the rest of the list is in descending order, and the first element is greater than the second, then the list is in descending order:

```
                | Both <- sort_yxs, x > y = Descending
                | Ascending <- sort_yxs, > y = Descending
    where sort_yxs = sorted (y:xs)
```

In all the remaining cases, it means that some part(s) of the list are `Ascending` and some part(s) are `Descending`, so then the list is `NotSorted`.

```
                | otherwise = NotSorted
```

or putting these all together:

```
sorted [] = Both
sorted [_] = Both
sorted (x:y:xs) | Both <- sort_yxs, x < y = Ascending
                | Ascending <- sort_yxs, x < y = Ascending
                | Both <- sort_yxs, x > y = Descending
                | Ascending <- sort_yxs, x > y = Descending
                | otherwise = NotSorted
    where sort_yxs = sorted (y:xs)
```

## Refactoring: make `TypeOfSort` a `Monoid`

The above definition contains a lot of edge cases, this makes it hard to write a simple program. We can make it easier by introducing some utility functions. This can for instance be done by defining a function that takes two `TypeOfSort`s and then returns the intersection. Such a function could look like:

```
intersect Both x = x
intersect x Both = x
intersect Ascending Ascending = Ascending
intersect Descending Descending = Descending
intersect _ _ = NotSorted
```

This actually forms a *monoid* with `Both` as identity element:

```
instance Monoid where
    mappend Both x = x
    mappend x Both = x
    mappend Ascending Ascending = Ascending
    mappend Descending Descending = Descending
    mappend _ _ = NotSorted

    mempty = Both
```

Now we can rewrite our definition as:

```
sorted [] = Both
sorted [_] = Both
sorted (x:y:ys) | x > y = mappend rec Ascending
                | x < y = mappend rec Descending
                | otherwise = NotSorted
    where rec = sorted (y:ys)
```

Comment: thank you for your clear answer but it gave me parse error on input '|'...

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation sir!

Comment: @JayRowen: yes, when merging the fragments together something went wrong.

Comment: @WillNess: that was exactly why I was building up to the argument that this is a bad idea: because unfortunately a salary is too high to pay people to look for typos :)

Comment: also, why shouldn't `sorted (1:3:2:undefined)` return `NotSorted`.

Comment: @WillNess: because then I had to write two intermezzo section(s) about `undefined`, and about accumulators in the answer, and sometimes people work to earn a living (and something extra). But feel free to write an answer yourself.

Comment: In both the non-monoidal version and the monoidal version you are missing the x == y case. You are currently returning NotSorted instead of intersecting Both with the outcome of the rest.

Comment: @Potato44: but this is mentioned in the answer, we assume strict ordering. But it is easy to generalize the code.

Answer (score 4):

My solution without using the sort function and without recursion :

```
data SortType = Ascending | Descending | NotSorted | Flat | Unknown deriving (Show)

sorted :: (Ord a) => [a] -> SortType 
sorted [] = Unknown
sorted [a] = Flat
sorted xs  
    | and [x == y | (x, y) <- zipPairs xs] = Flat
    | and [x <= y | (x, y) <- zipPairs xs] = Ascending
    | and [x >= y | (x, y) <- zipPairs xs] = Descending
    | otherwise                            = NotSorted

zipPairs :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
zipPairs xs = zip xs (tail xs)
```

Faster is probably the one using lambdas

```
all (\(x, y) -> x <= y) (zipPairs xs)
```

In Python I would probably do something like this

```
from itertools import izip, islice

n = len(lst)

all(x <= y for x, y in izip(islice(lst, 0, n - 1), islice(lst, 1, n)))
```

Comment: you don't need `init`. also, your version will properly return `NotSorted` for `[1,3,2,1/0]` after examining only the first three of its elements, as it ought to; kudos for that. you could also have another clause, `| and [x == y | (x, y) <- zipCustom xs] = Flat`; and maybe call the result for `[]` "Unknown" (similar to Redu's answer).

Comment: yes you do, and yes it is, due to Haskell's laziness. It will work fine on infinite lists, and detect `NotSorted` as soon as possible. Unlike Willem's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you may also do as follows;

```
data Sorting = Why | Karma | Flat | Descent | Ascent deriving (Show)

howSorted :: Ord a => [a] -> Sorting
howSorted xs | xs == []                    = Why
             | all (== head xs) $ tail xs  = Flat
             | and $ map (uncurry (<=)) ts = Ascent
             | and $ map (uncurry (>=)) ts = Descent
             | otherwise                   = Karma
             where ts = zip xs $ tail xs
```

Comment: `a==True` is the same as `a`.

Comment: @Will Ness this is one silly mistake i can never stop making regardless of the time. Lucky me it's harmless.

Answer (score 1):

We have an implementation of [sort](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sort) already, from Data.List that we can use to achieve this.

```
import Data.List (sort)

sorted xs 
    | sort xs == xs = Ascending
    | reverse (sort xs) == xs = Descending
    | otherwise = NotSorted
```

If the sorted list is equal to the list, then it must be sorted with an ascended sort.

If the sorted list, reversed, is equal to the list, then it must be sorted with a descended sort.

Otherwise, it's not sorted.

As @Benjamin-Hodgson points out, the edge conditions might need thinking about. With this implementation, an empty list counts as sorted, so does a list of one item, and so does a list of the same item repeated.

Usage:

```
λ> sorted [1..5]
Ascending
λ> sorted [5,4..1]
Descending
λ> sorted [1,3,1]
NotSorted
λ> sorted []
Ascending
λ> sorted [1]
Ascending
λ> sorted [1,1,1]
Ascending
```

Alternatively, we can use [sortBy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortBy) for the reverse case, to avoid having to reverse the list completely. This just sorts by the default comparison function, with the arguments flipped, so a less than becomes a greater than.

```
import Data.List (sort, sortBy)

sorted xs 
    | sort xs == xs = Ascending
    | sortBy (flip compare) xs == xs = Descending
    | otherwise = NotSorted
```

Comment: Actually sorting the list is inefficient. If the list is already sorted, you could determine that in O(n), while sorting could take as long as O(n lg n). If the list isn't sorted, you'll probably spend O(n lg n) time sorting it before making one or more linear-time passes to compare to the original, when as few as 2 comparisons on the original could tell you the list is unsorted.

Comment: @chepner True, Willem's answer is much more comprehensive anyway. I generally try and write clear code and optimize later which might not be the best idea