# Is there a multiple-condition if in Haskell?

Tags: if-statement, haskell

I was trying to nest guards which check for more than two conditions like so:

```
f :: Int -> Int
f i
   | bool1
       | bool2 = a
       | bool3 = a2
       | otherwise = a3
   | bool4
       | bool5 = a4
       | bool6 = a5
       | otherwise = a6
   | bool8
...
   | otherwise = an
```

which gives me a parse error.
Is the proper way to do this
   to flatten the guards with && or
   to implement a function like so:

```
multiIf :: [Bool] -> [a] -> a
multiIf (x:xs) (l:ls) = if x then l else multiIf xs ls
multiIf _ _ = undefined
```

Or is there another method?

Comment: Try the MultiWayIf extension.

Comment: Does this imply that if `bool7` is false, the outer branch is considered again and `bool8` is evaluated, and so on? Your `multiIf` does not do that, AFAICS.

Comment: @chi Thanks, I meant to use otherwise

Comment: while I'd admit it's not particularly nice, if you really need to write this sort of function then I'd probably just make a big `if/then/else` tree, with the proper indentation.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Minor point: technically `if` does not require any indentation (but pragmatically writing a large nested `if` without proper indentation leads to unreadable code, so its' still strongly recommended).

Comment: @chi, understood and agreed - that's all I meant

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to nest guards in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124558/is-it-possible-to-nest-guards-in-haskell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly, but [the MultiWayIf extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.5/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#multi-way-if-expressions) can get you a very similar style.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}

f :: Int -> Int
f i
   | bool1
       = if | bool2 -> a
            | bool3 -> a2
            | otherwise -> a3
   | bool4
       = if | bool5 -> a4
            | bool6 -> a5
            | otherwise -> a6
   | bool8
...
   | otherwise = an
```